# Delimiters in csv.writer creates additional quotes

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I've got an issue when trying to export my data to an Excel file through csv writer.

When I try to export it with the default delimiter (the comma), it does it correctly. This is the code with the default delimiter:

```
with open(file, 'w', encoding="utf-8", newline='') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.writer(csvfile, dialect='excel',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
```

Output:

```
"ID","Title","Genre","Country" 
"A4321","Film1","Horror","USA"
"A4322","Film2","Romance","France"
"A4323","Film3","Comedy","Germany"
"A4324","Film4","Western","UK"
```

And when I transform the text to columns in Excel through the comma separator, it separates it correctly in columns.

However, if I try to use the vertical bar (|) as delimiter, the output is quite weird, as it creates more quotes in the file. This is the code, in which I only add the specification of the delimiter:

```
with open(m_file, 'w', encoding="utf-8", newline='') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.writer(csvfile, dialect='excel', delimiter ='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
```

Output:

```
"ID"|"Title"|"Genre"|"Country" 
"A4321|""Film1""|""Horror""|""USA""
"A4322|""Film2""|"Romance""|"France""
"A4323|""Film3""|""Comedy""|""Germany""
"A4324|""Film4""|""Western""|""UK""
```

And the separation with the vertical bar delimiter doesn't work on Excel.

I've tried changing the *quoting*, adding *escapechars* and *doublequotes = False*, but it doesn't work

Should I change anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Unable to reproduce:

```
import csv

m_file = "tata.csv"

data = [["A","a", 5], 
        ["B","b", 7], 
        ["C","c", 9], 
        
]
with open(m_file, 'w', encoding="utf-8", newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, dialect='excel', delimiter ='|',
                        quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    writer.writerows(data)

with open(m_file) as f:
    print(f.read())
```

File content:

```
"A"|"a"|5
"B"|"b"|7
"C"|"c"|9
```

Changing data to

```
data = [["A","a", 5], 
        ["B","b", 7], 
        ['"C"','"c"', 9],
```

leads to

```
"A"|"a"|5        
"B"|"b"|7        
"""C"""|"""c"""|9
```

still not what you got.